# How to write a test for a stateful widget?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, widget, flutter-test

I have a stateful widget whose state depends on a async firebase database read call. While the data is being fetched, I display a waiting circular indicator. Once, data fetch is finished, I display the actual ListView widget.

I want to write a widget test to test this functionality. 
How do i set the value of isReadComplete = true in my test? Or
How can I explicitly call success_callback() from my test?

```
bool isReadComplete;

App(){
   isReadComplete = false;

   firestore.collection('collection').document('doc').get().then((doc) {
      success_callback(doc.data);
    }).catchError((error) => {});
}


void success_callback(var data){
   setState((){
      isReadComplete = true;
   })
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!isReadComplete) {
      return new CircularIndicator();
    } else {
      List<Widget> widgetList = [];      
      return Scaffold(
          body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        children: widgetList,
      ));
    }
  }

// Test for CircularProgressIndicator

testWidgets("Check CircularProgressIndicator", (WidgetTester tester) async {

      await tester.pumpWidget(new MaterialApp(home: App));

      // This works fine since isReadComplete = false
      expect(find.byType(CircularProgressIndicator), findsOneWidget);
    });

// Test for ListView

testWidgets("Check ListView", (WidgetTester tester) async {

      await tester.pumpWidget(new MaterialApp(home: App));

      // How do I do this? 
      // How to call success_callback()?
      // How to set isReadComplete = true?
      expect(find.byType(ListView), findsOneWidget);
    });
```

Comment: What causes `success_callback` to be called? You'll want to reproduce what causes the `success_callback` call and then read the value from your state object in your test. There's an example of testing a stateful widget [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/test/widgets/stateful_components_test.dart)

Comment: That is a callback after a database call is successful. I put it in the code now. I do not want to do a database read/write in a test.

Comment: did you find any ?

Comment: No I did not. But I believe this can be done by moving the code to a controller class.

Answer (score 3):

After `pumpWidget()`, you'd need to call [`pump()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/pump.html) with a Duration set to listen if the Future finishes within the set amount of time. An alternative to `pump()` is `pumpAndSettle()` - which calls `pump` at least once and may repeatedly call `pump` within a given duration.

```dart
await tester.pumpWidget(new MaterialApp(home: App));
await tester.pumpAndSettle();
```